# Hierarchical Bayesian analysis on difference of proportions

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

**Why Hierarchical? :** I've tried researching this problem, and from what I understand, this is a "hierarchical" problem, because you are making observations about observations from a population, rather than making direct observations from that population. 
Reference: http://www.econ.umn.edu/~bajari/iosp07/rossi1.pdf

**Why Bayesian? :** Also, I've tagged it as Bayesian because an asymptotic/frequentist solution may exist for an "experimental design" wherein each "cell" is assigned sufficient observations, but for practical purposes real-world/non-experimental data sets (or at least mine) are sparsely populated. There's a lot of aggregate data, but individual cells may be blank or have just a few observations.

**The model in abstract:**

Let U be a population of units ${u_1, u_2, u_3 ... u_N}$ to each of which we can apply a treatment, $T$, of either $A$ or $B$, and from each of which we observe i.i.d. observations of either 1 or 0 a.k.a. successes and failures. Let $p_{iT}$ for $i \in \{1...N\}$ be the probability that an observation from object $i$ under treatment $T$ results in a success. Note that $p_{iA}$ may be correlated with $p_{iB}$.

To make the analysis feasible, we (a) assume that the distributions $p_A$ and $p_B$ are each an instance of a specific family of distributions, such as the beta distribution, (b) and select some prior distributions for hyperparameters.

**Example of the model**

I have a really big bag of Magic 8 Balls. Each 8-ball, when shaken, can reveal "Yes", or "No". Also, I can shake them with the ball right-side-up, or upside-down (assuming our Magic 8 Balls work upside-down...). The orientation of the ball may completely change the probability of resulting in a "Yes" or a "No" (in other words, initially you have no belief that $p_{iA}$ is correlated with $p_{iB}$).

**Questions:**

Someone has randomly sampled a number, $n$, of units from the population, and for each unit has taken and recorded an arbitrary number of observations under treatment $A$ and an arbitrary number of observations under treatment $B$. (In practice, in our data set, most units will have observations only under one treatment)

Given this data, I need to answer the following questions:

1. If I take a new unit $u_x$ randomly from the population, how can I calculate (analytically or stochastically) the joint posterior distribution of $p_{xA}$ and $p_{xB}$? (Primarily so that we can determine the expected difference in proportions, $\Delta=p_{xA}-p_{xB}$)
2. For a specific unit $u_y$, $y \in \{1,2,3...,n\}$, with observations of $s_y$ successes and $f_y$ failures, how can I calculate (analytically or stochastically) the joint posterior distribution for $p_{yA}$ and $p_{yB}$, again to build a distribution $\Delta_y$ of the difference in proportions $p_{yA}-p_{yB}$

Bonus question: Although we really do expect $p_A$ and $p_B$ to be very correlated, we are not explicitly modeling that. In the likely case of a stochastic solution, I believe this would cause some samplers, including Gibbs, the be less effective at exploring the posterior distribution. Is this the case, and if so, should we use a different sampler, somehow model the correlation as a separate variable and transform the $p$ distributions to make them uncorrelated, or just run the sampler longer?

**Answer criteria**

I'm looking for an answer that:

- Has code, using preferably Python/PyMC, or barring that, JAGS,  that I am able to run
- Is able to handle an input of thousands of units
- Given enough units and samples, is able to output distributions for $p_A$, $p_B$, and $\Delta$ as an answer to Question 1, that can be shown to match the underlying population distributions (to be checked against excel sheets provided in the "challenge datasets" section)
- Given enough units and samples, is able to output the right distributions for $p_A$, $p_B$, and $\Delta$ (I'll use the excel sheets provided in the "challenge datasets" section to check) as an answer to Question 2, and provides some rationale as to why these distributions are correct
- <s>If the answer is similar to the last JAGS model I posted, explain why it works with `dpar(0.5,1)` priors but not with `dgamma(2,20)` priors.</s> Thanks to Martyn Plummer on the [JAGS forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610036/thread/6cd68c6c/) for catching the error in my JAGS model. In trying to set a prior of Gamma(Shape=2,Scale=20), I was calling `dgamma(2,20)` which actually set a prior of Gamma(Shape=2,InverseScale=20) = Gamma(Shape=2,Scale=0.05).

**Challenge datasets**

I've generated a few sample datasets in Excel, with a few different possible scenarios, changing the tightness of the p distributions, the correlation between them, and making it easy to change other inputs.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_rPBjs4Cp0zLVBybU1nVnd0ZFU/edit?usp=sharing (~8Mb)

[image: A visualization of the 4 datasets included in the Excel file]

**My attempted/partial solution(s) to date**

**1)** I downloaded and installed Python 2.7 and PyMC 2.2. Initially, I got an incorrect model to run, but when I tried to reformulate the model, the extension freezes. By adding/removing code, I've determined the code that triggers the freeze is mc.Binomial(...) , though this function did work in the first model, so I assume there is something wrong with how I've specified the model.

```
import pymc as mc
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from __future__ import division
cases=[0,0]
for case in range(2):
    if case==0:
        # Taken from the sample datasets excel sheet, Focused Correlated p's
        c_A_arr, n_A_arr, c_B_arr, n_B_arr=np.loadtxt("data/TightCorr.tsv", unpack=True)

    if case==1:
        # Taken from the sample datasets excel sheet, Focused Uncorrelated p's
        c_A_arr, n_A_arr, c_B_arr, n_B_arr=np.loadtxt("data/TightUncorr.tsv", unpack=True)

    scale=20.0
    alpha_A=mc.Uniform("alpha_A", 1,scale)
    beta_A=mc.Uniform("beta_A", 1,scale)
    alpha_B=mc.Uniform("alpha_B", 1,scale)
    beta_B=mc.Uniform("beta_B", 1,scale)
    p_A=mc.Beta("p_A",alpha=alpha_A,beta=beta_A)
    p_B=mc.Beta("p_B",alpha=alpha_B,beta=beta_B)

    @mc.deterministic
    def delta(p_A=p_A,p_B=p_B):
        return p_A-p_B

    obs_n_A=mc.DiscreteUniform("obs_n_A",lower=0,upper=20,observed=True, value=n_A_arr)
    obs_n_B=mc.DiscreteUniform("obs_n_B",lower=0,upper=20,observed=True, value=n_B_arr)

    obs_c_A=mc.Binomial("obs_c_A",n=obs_n_A,p=p_A, observed=True, value=c_A_arr)
    obs_c_B=mc.Binomial("obs_c_B",n=obs_n_B,p=p_B, observed=True, value=c_B_arr)


    model = mc.Model([alpha_A,beta_A,alpha_B,beta_B,p_A,p_B,delta,obs_n_A,obs_n_B,obs_c_A,obs_c_B])
    cases[case] = mc.MCMC(model)
    cases[case].sample(24000, 12000, 2)

    lift_samples = cases[case].trace('delta')[:]

    ax = plt.subplot(211+case)
    figsize(12.5,5)
    plt.title("Posterior distributions of lift from 0 to T")
    plt.hist(lift_samples, histtype='stepfilled', bins=30, alpha=0.8,
             label="posterior of lift", color="#7A68A6", normed=True)
    plt.vlines(0, 0, 4, color="k", linestyles="--", lw=1)
    plt.xlim([-1, 1])
```

**2)** I downloaded and installed JAGS 3.4. After getting a correction on my priors from the JAGS forum, I now have this model, which successfully runs:

Model

```
var alpha_A, beta_A, alpha_B, beta_B, p_A[N], p_B[N], delta[N], n_A[N], n_B[N], c_A[N], c_B[N];
model {
    for (i in 1:N) {
        c_A[i] ~ dbin(p_A[i],n_A[i])
        c_B[i] ~ dbin(p_B[i],n_B[i])
        p_A[i] ~ dbeta(alpha_A,beta_A)
        p_B[i] ~ dbeta(alpha_B,beta_B)
        delta[i] <- p_A[i]-p_B[i]
    }
    alpha_A ~ dgamma(1,0.05)
    alpha_B ~ dgamma(1,0.05)
    beta_A ~ dgamma(1,0.05)
    beta_B ~ dgamma(1,0.05)
}
```

Data

```
"N" <- 60
"c_A" <- structure(c(0,6,0,3,0,8,0,4,0,6,1,5,0,5,0,7,0,3,0,7,0,4,0,5,0,4,0,5,0,4,0,2,0,4,0,5,0,8,2,7,0,6,0,3,0,3,0,8,0,4,0,4,2,6,0,7,0,3,0,1))
"c_B" <- structure(c(5,0,2,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,5,0,4,0,3,1,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,6,0,4,1,5,0,2,0,6,0,1,0,2,0,4,0,4,1,1,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,5,0,2,0,7,1))
"n_A" <- structure(c(0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3))
"n_B" <- structure(c(9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3,9,0,9,0,9,0,3,0,9,0,9,0,9,3))
```

Control

```
model in Try1.bug
data in Try1.r
compile, nchains(2)
initialize
update 400
monitor set p_A, thin(3)
monitor set p_B, thin(3)
monitor set delta, thin(3)
update 1000
coda *, stem(Try1)
```

**The actual application for anyone who would rather pick apart the model :)**

On the web, typical A/B testing considers the impact to conversion rate from a single page or unit of content, with possible variations. Typical solutions include a classical significance test against the null hypotheses or two equal proportions, or more recently analytical Bayesian solutions leveraging the beta distribution as a conjugate prior.

Instead of this single-unit-of-content approach, which incidentally would require a lot of visitors to each unit of I am interested in testing, we want to compare variations in a process that generates multiple units of content (not an unusual scenario really...). So on the whole, the units/pages produced by process A or B have a lot of visits/data, but each individual unit may only have a few observations.

Comment: You have skipped crucial aspects in your description. After you uniformly draw an $x$, what happens next? Something must, for otherwise you have absolutely no information about any of the $p_x$! Then, what do you observe? Do you observe $x$ and, say, an independent draw from $o_x$? Or do you just observe the draw from $o_x$ and do not record $x$? To estimate all these density distributions, surely you must repeat the process many, many times--how many? Or, by "estimate" do you assume you know all the $p_x$ and you would like to *calculate* the distribution of the outcome of your experiment?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the phrase "$x$ is uniformly drawn from 1...N" was misleading. Given a large number of existing observations about various $o_x$, I want to determine the distribution of $p_x$. It's somewhat analogous to sampling 50 people from a population, observing their heights, and then asking for the distribution of the height for a person "randomly drawn from the population". I just used uniform since the popuation in this case was enumerated, and I see it's confusing. (Continuing with the analogy, in this scenario, we don't get to measure the people, just observe a few binary responses)

Comment: I've added an example to the end of the question that hopefully makes it clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. The question remains confusing, though. In the example you are observing an *ordered pair* of values: times rolled and successes. Exactly what "distribution" are you inquiring about, then? Precisely what property of the big bag of dice would it correspond to?

Comment: The pair of values (rolls & successes) conveys information about a latent variable, p. The distribution I want is the distribution of p's in the bag. Of course, if we don't assume a class of distributions that it belongs to, there are arbitrarily many possibilities, but if we say that p is for example beta-distributed, then it comes down to just selecting the best fitting parameters for this class of distributions. If it helps, now consider instead of dice with p=1/4,1/6,1/8, that each object has a p from Beta(2,2)... or Beta (4,4), etc.

Comment: @BabakP - In any case, would certainly appreciate that answer and would consider it very useful. I can personally run the R answer. However, the final goal is to use be able to call this functionality from our codebase. So, I would award the bounty to such an answer only if there existed a well-documented way to invoke this R solution from either a Java or Python written programs running on a Windows environment. Also, performance would become a consideration in who gets the bounty since I imagine there is little we could do to optimize or parallelize it like we could do in Python or Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the time for the bounty expired and I received no answers, I'll post the answer I was able to come up with, though my limited experience with Bayesian inference suggests that this should be taken with a healthy dose of skepticism.

**I)** Setup

1. I downloaded & installed JAGS 3.4 and R 3.0.1
2. I installed the packages rjags and coda by initiating R and using install.packages(pkgname)

**II)** Model & Data - Used the model & data files already detailed in the question. To answer question #1, I added one additional observation onto the data with all four variables as 0.

**III)** Answering questions

1. I ran JAGS on the model/data (open the command line, go the the directory with your files, and type > jags-terminal Command.cmd . It ran and output a few files
2. In R, I used the following commands:

   - library("rjags") to load the installed package (and its required package coda)
   - setwd() to get to the directory where the outputfiles were
   - results=read.coda("STEMchain1.txt","STEMindex.txt")
3. To answer the first question:

   - As a PDF plot, "plot(results[,3*N])"
   - As quantiles, "quantile(results[,3*N],c(0.025,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.975))"
   - Where N is the number of observations, and the last observation corresponds to the position of the "all 0's" observation. (1 to n is for variable p_A, n+1 to 2n is for p_B, and 2n+1 to 3n is for delta)
4. To answer the second question, same as above, but change 3*N -> 2*N+y

I'm not sure this is the correct way to get the answer, or whether a more complex model would produce better results, particularly in the case of correlation, but hopefully eventually someone more experienced will chime in...